# Как правильно конвертировать datetime64 в hour?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Есть DataFrame (df). В нем колонка-признак - `created` в формате `datetime64`. В колонке записана дата - `2017-04-02 13:58:51`. Когда извлекаю часы из даты вот так:

```
df['created_hour'] = df['created'].dt.hour
```

, то получаю значение 13. Хотя очевидно, что правильнее было бы записать 14, так как уже 58 минут. Но в лоб не получается это решить.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Может добавить timedelta в 30 минут сначала, а потом брать dt.hour )

Comment: `df['created'].dt.round('H').dt.hour`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov оформите, пожалуйста, свой комментарий как ответ.

Comment: Если какой-то ответ решил ваш вопрос, то поставьте галку слева от него

Answer (score 4):

У объекта `datetime` есть метод `round()`, который округляет время до указанного параметра и возвращает новый объект `datetime`.

Список возможных параметров приведен [здесь](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases)

- B business day frequency
- C custom business day frequency
- D calendar day frequency
- W weekly frequency
- M month end frequency
- SM semi-month end frequency (15th and end of month)
- BM business month end frequency
- CBM custom business month end frequency
- MS month start frequency
- SMS semi-month start frequency (1st and 15th)
- BMS business month start frequency
- CBMS custom business month start frequency
- Q quarter end frequency
- BQ business quarter end frequency
- QS quarter start frequency
- BQS business quarter start frequency
- A, Y year end frequency
- BA, BY business year end frequency
- AS, YS year start frequency
- BAS, BYS business year start frequency
- BH business hour frequency
- **H hourly frequency**
- T, min minutely frequency
- S secondly frequency
- L, ms milliseconds
- U, us microseconds
- N nanoseconds

Т.е. вам нужно текущий `datetime` округлить до часов (модификатор `H`), а затем у нового объекта запросить количество часов.

Итого:

```
df['created'].dt.round('H').dt.hour
```

Answer (score 2):

Пример:

```
In [61]: df
Out[61]:
   user_id   timestamp                date
0      313  1491144981 2017-04-02 14:56:21
1       20  1491180276 2017-04-03 00:44:36

In [62]: df["created_hour"] = df["date"].dt.hour + df["date"].dt.minute.ge(30)

In [63]: df
Out[63]:
   user_id   timestamp                date  created_hour
0      313  1491144981 2017-04-02 14:56:21            15
1       20  1491180276 2017-04-03 00:44:36             1
```

но более идиоматично воспользоваться [вариантом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1161646/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-pandas-datetime-hour/1161667#comment2014910_1161646) от `@Anton Shchyrov`